# Returning array from function gives unexpected result C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

Im trying to learn C++ with Qt creator and now I cant output correct result.
My program should read numbers from QTableWidget and output the lowest. And sometimes it works, but often there is smth like 201-e302. I don't know why. I should make it with dynamic arrays. Thats my teacher's task.

---

Here`s my code:

```
    QPair<int, double*> Widget::count()
{
    double *arr = new double[0];
    bool ok;
    int len = 0;
 //Reading numbers from QTablewidget
    for (int row = 0; row < ui->table->rowCount(); row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < ui->table->columnCount(); col++)
        {
            if(ui->table->item(row, col) and
                    ui->table->item(row, col)->text().length() != 0)  
            {
                double *temp = new double[len + 1];
                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
                {
                    temp[j] = arr[j];
                }
                temp[len] = ui->table->item(row, col)->text().toDouble(&ok);
                arr = temp;
                delete [] temp;
                len++;
            }
            else
            {
                QPair<int, double*> res = qMakePair(0, arr);
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", "Fill every cell");
                return res;
            }
        }
//
    QPair<int, double*> res = qMakePair(len, arr);
    return res;
}

void Widget::on_min_but_clicked()
{
    int len = count().first;
    double* arr = count().second;
    if (len != 0)
    {
        double min = arr[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] < min)
            {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        ui->min_lineedit->setText(QString::number(min));
    }
}
```

Comment: use `std::vector<double>` instead of `double *` and `new[]`, and don't be surprised if your issues disappear.  There is little reason for end-user C++ apps to use `new[]` and `delete[]` for dynamic arrays -- that is the job of `std::vector`.

Comment: I should make it with dynamic arrays. Thats my teacher's task. Is there any other ways?

Comment: So you are allowed to use a third-party framework like Qt, but not allowed to use `std::vector`, a container that has been part of the standard C++ library for over 20 years?  Now I've heard everything.

Comment: Can you help with this task?

Comment: [Yes sure](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c4e3a66f39ad2f3).  Create your own vector class.  That uses dynamic arrays, but wrapped in a class.  Even Qt has their own vector class, so why are you not using it?

Comment: [QVector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html).  So you need to question as to what the goal is of your program -- is it to create a Qt app, or to fumble around with faulty `new[]` and `delete[]` logic, slowing down your progress in completing the Qt app?

Comment: Thanks. That`s really cool advice

Comment: Yes, if you use Qt, there are container classes already created for you to use.  You shouldn't resort to low-level `new[]` and `delete[]` calls.

Comment: I think instead of `arr = temp;` in the code that is in the question you can do `std::swap(arr,temp);`

Answer (score 2):

In this code snippet you are allocating a new array, assigning a pointer to that array, then deleting that array.

```
double *temp = new double[len + 1];
arr = temp;
delete [] temp;
```

This leaves `arr` with a dangling pointer to deleted memory. I would suggest changing the type to `std::vector<double> arr`.

Comment: Thanks, but I should do it with dynamic arrays. That's the task